# Convert from query to method

Tags: c#, linq

How to convert following code to method operator:

```
var myOrders = from c in customers
               where c.Field<string>("Region") == "WA"
               from o in orders
               where c.Field<string>("CustomerID") == o.Field<string>("CustomerID")
               && (DateTime)o["OrderDate"] >= cutoffDate
               select new { 
                  CustomerID = c.Field<string>("CustomerID"), 
                  OrderID = o.Field<int>("OrderID") 
               };
```

---------or----------

```
 var myOrders = from c in customers
               where c.Region == "WA"
               from o in orders
               where c.CustomerID == o.CustomerID
               && o.OrderDate >= cutoffDate
               select new { 
                  CustomerID = c.CustomerID, 
                  OrderID = o.OrderID 
               };
```

same code in  object form

Comment: What have you tried? And why do you want to do it at all? (It's likely to be uglier than the query expression form...) Any reason you don't want to actually do a *join* on `CustomerID`?

Comment: @JonSkeet i took the example from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825      SelectMany - Multiple from

Comment: I don't have an IDE around to check it out, but I went the SelectMany route in my answer (below).  The MSDN commentary for this example says it is trying to optimize the query by not selecting all orders, but I would imagine that a .Join will probably benefit the same optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd actually rewrite this as a join - probably via intermediate variables:

```
var washingtonCustomers = customers.Where(c => c.Field<string>("Region") == "WA");
var recentOrders = orders.Where(o => (DateTime)o["OrderDate"] >= cutoffDate);

var query = washingtonCustomers.Join(recentOrders, 
                 c => c.Field<string>("CustomerID"),
                 o => o.Field<string>("CustomerID"),
                 (c, o) => new { 
                     CustomerID = c.Field<string>("CustomerID"), 
                     OrderID = o.Field<int>("OrderID") 
                 });
```

Comment: I took the example from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-09787825      SelectMany - Multiple from

Comment: Also, it will query Db three times and recentOrders will fetch all the orders irrespective of customer.

Comment: @nin - Actually, it won't. Because of Linq's deferred execution, the first two lines won't actually cause any queries to execute. In fact, *none* of the Jon's code will cause a query to execute - it's all just building up a query to be executed later. Only when you actually iterate through the results will the DB be queried.  So, while my answer is probably the most direct answer to your question, Jon's answer is likely the better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just wanting to use the functional Linq syntax instead of query syntax?  That would look like:

```
var myOrders = customers
  .Where(c => c.Region == "WA")
  .SelectMany(c => 
    orders
      .Where(o => (o.CustomerID == c.CustomerID)
        && (o.OrderDate > cutoffDate))
      .Select(o => new {
           CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
           OrderID = o.OrderID
         })
   );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code - based on  `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Int32>`

```
public  IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Int32>> YourQuery(DateTime date, string code)
{

           var result = 
           from c in customers
           where c.Field<string>("Region") == code

           from o in orders
           where c.Field<string>("CustomerID") == o.Field<string>("CustomerID")
               && (DateTime)o["OrderDate"] >= date

           select new 
           { 
              CustomerID = c.Field<string>("CustomerID"), 
              OrderID = o.Field<int>("OrderID") 
           };

           return result;
}
```